# Can I change workload on a Datastax enterprise cluster?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I'm running DSE 4.8.16 cluster with search configured. Can I change the workload from 'search' to only running dse cassandra? And if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to edit /etc/default/dse and set `SOLR_ENABLED=0`. After that restart dse.